# TypeScript and createContext - Property is missing on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Fairly new to TypeScript and trying to get the hang of data values and types.

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react'

const defaultValues = {
    id: undefined
}

type AuthenticatedUser = typeof defaultValues

export const UserContext = createContext<AuthenticatedUser>(defaultValues)
export const UserProvider = (props: { children?: React.ReactChild }) => {
    const [authenticatedUser, setAuthenticatedUser] = useState<AuthenticatedUser>(defaultValues)
    const { children } = props

    return (
        <UserContext.Provider value={[authenticatedUser, setAuthenticatedUser]}>
            {children}
        </UserContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

This gives me the following error

> Property 'id' is missing in type '({ id: undefined; } | Dispatch<SetStateAction<{ id: undefined; }>>)[]' but required in type '{ id: undefined; }'.ts(2741)

I have tried all kinds of combinations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `UserContext.Provider`, the `value` is expecting a type of { id: undefined } but you are currently assigning the `value` to the provider of type `({ id: undefined; } | Dispatch<SetStateAction<{ id: undefined; }>>)[]`.

Here, we are supplying the provider with an array of type `({ id: undefined; } | Dispatch<SetStateAction<{ id: undefined; }>>)[]` instead of the expected type of `{ id: undefined }`

```
<UserContext.Provider value={[authenticatedUser, setAuthenticatedUser]}>
  {children}
</UserContext.Provider>;
```

If we supply the `Provider` with just `value={authenticatedUser}`, we can see that the error goes away.

```
 <UserContext.Provider value={authenticatedUser}>
      {children}
 </UserContext.Provider>;
```

From what I can see, I think you want to be able to change the User from anywhere in your app. You'll need to setup a function on your UserProviderthat allows you to login, logout, etc.

```
export const UserProvider = (props: { children?: React.ReactChild }) => {
  const [authenticatedUser, setAuthenticatedUser] = useState(defaultValues);
  const { children } = props;

  const login = () => {};
  const logout = () => {};
  const register = () => {};

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={authenticatedUser}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

## 07/07/2021 Update

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";

type User = {
  id: number | undefined;
};

type UserContextType = {
  user?: User;
  login: () => void;
  logout: () => void;
};

export const UserContext = createContext<UserContextType>(
  {} as UserContextType
);

export const UserProvider = (props: { children?: React.ReactChild }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<User>();
  const { children } = props;

  const login = () => {};
  const logout = () => {};

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ user, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for this explanation, how would I access these functions to change the user? I can't export the functions itself

Comment: You would need to change the type for your provider to accept an object of type: {id: undefined, login: () => void ... etc., to return that in your context. Then, when you useContext(UserContext) you can access those functions.

Comment: Can I read about this somewhere? I am not getting it to work. How do I return the function in my context?

Answer (score 0):

#### Problem explanation

You created `UserContext` with type `AuthenticatedUser`, but you are passing in an array (`value={[authenticatedUser, setAuthenticatedUser]}`) in your jsx.

#### Fix

Change this:

```
<UserContext.Provider value={[authenticatedUser, setAuthenticatedUser]}>
```

to this:

```
<UserContext.Provider value={authenticatedUser}>
```

If you want access to the setter via your context, you will have to change the type of `UserContext` to something like this:

```
// Note: defaultValues will be invalid here.
export const UserContext = createContext<[AuthenticatedUser, React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<AuthenticatedUser>>]>(defaultValues);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecCuAzkgMowoxLZpSqUDCEAdpQB7wC%20cAZlBCHADktdDEEAocWmaF4AEyTcU%20ADYwAaihX4khOAF5c4uCbjA5ALgJMF3YEyRzxHSTACeYJHACC%20GAAskFmA0CkcAVWIoAzh3TwhuOFtlNU1tXUkkVkhYOGkmWThIpChGFiz4Qxo6JDK2GAAeXwCgmBCwuWKoAD4ACmTVDS0dQgBKcSyc%20HzCroAFPgA3cxKY3rA%20MEIrPDR-YBU5WiYAfitkUQA6C4x6fcO4DlGDbqNTPJl4AG1lFuDQyidKLYYgwZqBf4dLoAXRiRFI5EoTT8ELaAIiUT6A1Sw1043eM3gu3uRyCjxiGwgW0k71oMHwUCYcF6xnepgaXTqFUuCwgywU0UWuP0OF%20qPagK6HG6rLZbJwewOpKYLjlJgaAHpOcx6jyliserK4OMOEA).